# React Form Axios Post Request to MongoDB 404 Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to make a simple form in React where the user answers a questions to create a persona and this data is stored in MongoDB. However, when I make an Axios post request, I get a 404 error. My post request urls match in both my server.js and CreatePersona.js, so I am not sure where I went wrong.

CreatePersona.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const AddStaff = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            await axios.post('/api', {
                title: title,
                content: content
            });

            console.log('Data posted to MongoDB Atlas successfully');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error posting data to MongoDB Atlas:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Posting data from HTML to MongoDB Atlas</h1>
            <form className="container" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        className="form-control"
                        name="title"
                        value={title}
                        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
          <textarea
              className="form-control"
              name="content"
              value={content}
              onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Add to MongoDB</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AddStaff;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose").default;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");



const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://firstlasname:Passwrod@database.6vwwqff.mongodb.net/myDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to MongoDB Atlas");
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log("Server is running on port " + port);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB Atlas:", error);
    });


const staffSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String
});


const Staff = mongoose.model("Staff", staffSchema);


app.post("/api", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        
        const newStaff = new Staff({
            title: req.body.title,
            content: req.body.content
        });

       
        await newStaff.save();

       
        res.send("Data posted to MongoDB Atlas successfully");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error posting data to MongoDB Atlas:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Error posting data to MongoDB Atlas");
    }
});
```

Error posting data to MongoDB ATlast: Axios error (message: 'Request failed with status code 404', code: 'ERR_BAD_Request'

I tried switching over from Axios to mongoose but I could not resolve the errors: `mongoose.connect` was `connect is not a function` or `cannot read properties of undefined connect`

Comment: const mongoose = require("mongoose").default; this line is alright?  Why there is a ".default" ?

Comment: Adding `default` causes `mongoose.connect() is not a function` so I need the `default` for it to run

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue might be with the URL you're using in your Axios post request
can you try the full URL

```
await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api', {
  title: title,
  content: content
});
```

- And for mongoose i think you are using old version that doesn't support `default` you can try with

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

- Then, you can use mongoose.connect to connect to your MongoDB Atlas instance. Here's an example:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB Atlas");
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port " + port);
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB Atlas:", error);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I change it to the full url I get the same error. Also adding `default` causes `mongoose.connect() is not a function` so I need the `default` for it to run.